# Trying to make a toolbox from script buffer to erase to make feature layer

Tags: arcpy, buffer, erase

I am trying to take a script that I edited from a ModelBuilder export. I am trying to plug it back in to make a tool that will buffer then erase, and then make feature layers.

What am I doing wrong?

I receive the following error message:

```
Buffer Complete 
Buffer Failed 
Erase Complete 
Erase Failed 
Failed script Hi...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skail\Desktop\hi.py", line 34, in <module>
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, buffmile_Erase_Layer)
NameError: name 'buffmile_Erase_Layer' is not defined
```

Script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'C:\Users\skail\Desktop\Project - Copy'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
Good_Food_Urban = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Good_Food_Urban == '#' or not Good_Food_Urban:
    Good_Food_Urban = "Good Food Urban.shp" 

County_Blocks = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if County_Blocks == '#' or not County_Blocks:
    County_Blocks = "County_Blocks.shp"

out_feature_class = "Results.shp"


# variables:
buff_shp = "buffermile.shp"
bufferase_Erase = "buffermile_Erase.shp"
bufferase_Erase_Layer = "buffermile_Erase_Layer"

# Process: Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Good_Food_Urban, buff_shp, "1 Miles", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "", "PLANAR")
arcpy.AddMessage("Buffer Complete")
arcpy.AddError("Buffer Failed")

# Process: Erase
arcpy.Erase_analysis(County_Blocks, buff_shp, bufferase_Erase)
arcpy.AddMessage("Erase Complete")
arcpy.AddError("Erase Failed")

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, buffmile_Erase_Layer)
arcpy.AddMessage("Layer Complete")
arcpy.AddError("Erase Failed")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(bufferase_Erase_Layer, Result_shp)
arcpy.AddMessage("Success!!")
arcpy.AddError("FAILED")
```

Comment: Getting closer my new error reads "NameError: name 'buff1_shp' is not defined"

Comment: Check the line `buffl_shp = "buffer1mile.shp"`. It seems you made a typo and wrote `buffl_shp` instead of `buff1_shp` (wrote the letter l instead of the number 1).

Comment: Buffer Complete
Buffer Failed
Erase Complete
Erase Failed
Failed script Hi...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skail\Desktop\hi.py", line 34, in <module>
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, buffmile_Erase_Layer)
NameError: name 'buffmile_Erase_Layer' is not defined

Comment: Seems that everything is still failing. I took out all numbers to be sure that there wasn't a mix up. Removed all try and except. I have also tried adding .shp after the layers that are coming up errors.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to revise it to where you are currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the script that you have presented you will see that you have not defined a variable named `buffmile_Erase_Layer` anywhere prior to trying to use it in the line which throws the error:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, buffmile_Erase_Layer)
```

If you want to make a feature layer named "buffmile_Erase_Layer". try this instead:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, "buffmile_Erase_Layer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `bufferase_Erase_Layer = "buffermile_Erase_Layer"` and then use the variable `buffmile_Erase_Layer` instead.

Change the line to:

`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bufferase_Erase, bufferase_Erase_Layer)`